# Convert XML tag to specific format

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have one ASP file, which I have to read. After reading the ASP file I have to convert some XML format to some specific format. Below is my code:

```
<%
dim sbixml, html, oHtml, xml, xml_, http, api

<sbixml>
<NetSightMessage>
<Header>
<UserID>GARY</UserID>
<Connection>Production</Connection>
<CurrentLedgers GL="GL" JL="JL"/>
<Mask>POUPPR</Mask>
<SubSystem>Purchasing</SubSystem>
<Trace Enabled="0"/>
<Timeout>30000</Timeout>
</Header>
<Request Type="ScreenXML">
<ScreenXML>
<ProgID>BT20.PENameMaster</ProgID>
</ScreenXML>
</Request>
</NetSightMessage>
</sbixml>

set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.async = false
xml.loadxml sbixml

api = "http://ebparksapp.ebparks.sungardpsasp.com/Finance/xml/schema/custom/ebparks/ebparks.asp?ebparks=" & sbixml
Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

http.Open "GET", api, False
http.Send 

set xml_ = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xml_.loadxml http.responseText

for each Detail in xml_.selectNodes("//Detail")
  response.write "<" & xml.selectsinglenode("//ReportFormat").getAttribute("wrap") & ">"
  for each Det in xml.selectNodes("//Detail")
    response.write "<" & Det.getAttribute("wrap") & ">" & Detail.getAttribute(Det.getAttribute("Prop")) & "</" & Det.getAttribute("wrap") & ">"
  next
  response.write "</" & xml.selectsinglenode("//ReportFormat").getAttribute("wrap") & ">"
next
%>
```

Here is the Output that is expected:

```
<%
dim sbixml, html, oHtml, xml, xml_, http, api

sbixml = "<sbixml>" & _
"<NetSightMessage>" & _
"<Header>" & _
"<UserID>GARY</UserID>" & _
"<Connection>Production</Connection>" & _
"<CurrentLedgers GL=""GL"" JL=""JL""/>" & _
"<Mask>POUPPR</Mask>" & _
"<SubSystem>Purchasing</SubSystem>" & _
"<Trace Enabled=""0""/>" & _
"<Timeout>30000</Timeout>" & _
"</Header>" & _
"<Request Type=""ScreenXML"">" & _
"<ScreenXML>" & _
"<ProgID>BT20.POPPvDetail</ProgID>" & _
"</ScreenXML>" & _
"</Request>" & _
"</NetSightMessage>" & _
"</sbixml>"

set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.async = false
xml.loadxml sbixml

api = "http://ebparksapp.ebparks.sungardpsasp.com/Finance/xml/schema/custom/ebparks/ebparks.asp?ebparks=" & sbixml
Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

http.Open "GET", api, False
http.Send 

set xml_ = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xml_.loadxml http.responseText

for each Detail in xml_.selectNodes("//Detail")
  response.write "<" & xml.selectsinglenode("//ReportFormat").getAttribute("wrap") & ">"
  for each Det in xml.selectNodes("//Detail")
    response.write "<" & Det.getAttribute("wrap") & ">" & Detail.getAttribute(Det.getAttribute("Prop")) & "</" & Det.getAttribute("wrap") & ">"
  next
  response.write "</" & xml.selectsinglenode("//ReportFormat").getAttribute("wrap") & ">"
next 
%>
```

Comment: Do you want to modify the code of your ASP file, or do you want to modify the XML loaded in your ASP file?

Comment: I want to modify XML loaded in my ASP file.

Comment: The code samples in your question say you want to modify your ASP file. If you want to modify the XML loaded in the page: what exactly do you want to modify about it?

Comment: Sorry for creating Confusion. I want to load ASP file and modify above XML Tags and then save ASP File.

Comment: Want to modify below XML


<sbixml>
<NetSightMessage>
<Header>
<UserID>GARY</UserID>
<Connection>Production</Connection>
<CurrentLedgers GL="GL" JL="JL"/>
<Mask>POUPPR</Mask>
<SubSystem>Purchasing</SubSystem>
<Trace Enabled="0"/>
<Timeout>30000</Timeout>
</Header>
<Request Type="ScreenXML">
<ScreenXML>
<ProgID>BT20.PENameMaster</ProgID>
</ScreenXML>
</Request>
</NetSightMessage>
</sbixml>

to

Comment: to this format
sbixml = "<sbixml>" & _
"<NetSightMessage>" & _
"<Header>" & _
"<UserID>GARY</UserID>" & _
"<Connection>Production</Connection>" & _
"<CurrentLedgers GL=""GL"" JL=""JL""/>" & _
"<Mask>POUPPR</Mask>" & _
"<SubSystem>Purchasing</SubSystem>" & _
"<Trace Enabled=""0""/>" & _
"<Timeout>30000</Timeout>" & _
"</Header>" & _
"<Request Type=""ScreenXML"">" & _
"<ScreenXML>" & _
"<ProgID>BT20.POPPvDetail</ProgID>" & _
"</ScreenXML>" & _
"</Request>" & _
"</NetSightMessage>" & _
"</sbixml>"

Comment: So actually you *do* want to modify your ASP file. Open it in an editor and change that. Why are you trying to do this with VBScript?

Comment: Because I have millions of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all your files have the XML *en bloc* with each line starting and ending with a tag (i.e. an angular bracket) and no blank lines between them you could do something like this (using a [replacement function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx#scripting12_topic4)):

```
foldername = "..."

Function MakeXmlVar(m, sm, pos, src)
  s = Replace(sm, """", """""")
  s = Split(sm, vbNewLine)
  For i = 0 To UBound(s)
    s(i) = """" & s(i) & """"
    If i <> UBound(s) Then s(i) = s(i) & " & _"
  Next
  MakeXmlVar = "sbixml = " & Join(s, vbNewLine)
End Function

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(<.*>(?:\r\n<.*>)*)"

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(foldername).Files
  txt = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll
  f.OpenAsTextStream(2).Write re.Replace(txt, GetRef("MakeXmlVar"))
Next
```

Comment: what are these Parameters:- m, sm, pos, src 

m,pos and src are not used in your exmaple.

only sm is used So what does sm mean here?

Comment: They are required parameters for this replacement function. `m` is short for "match" (the original match of the regexp), `sm` for "submatch" (the group in the regexp), `pos` is the position in the string, and `src` the source string. Even if the parameters are not used they must be defined, because `Replace()` passes these informations to the replacement function and will raise an error if the replacement function doesn't accept them.

Comment: it is throwing Error Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0036'

Bad file mode .

Comment: @Parveen Copy/paste error on my part. The file must be opened for writing in the second last line (default is to open for reading). See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Ansgar Wiechers code works,just modified for read & write at my end:-

```
  foldername = "E:\Code\vbscript\Files"
       Function MakeXmlVar(m, sm, pos, src)
          s = Replace(sm, """", """""")
          s = Split(sm, vbNewLine)
          For i = 0 To UBound(s)
            s(i) = """" & s(i) & """"
            If i <> UBound(s) Then s(i) = s(i) & " & _"
          Next
          MakeXmlVar = "sbixml = " & Join(s, vbNewLine)
        End Function

            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            Set re = New RegExp
            re.Pattern = "(<.*>(?:\r\n<.*>)*)"

            For Each f In fso.GetFolder(foldername).Files

             '***********For Reading*************
                Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

                Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(f, 1)

                strText = objFile.ReadAll
                objFile.Close

            '************For Writing*************
                Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(f, 2)
                strNewText=re.Replace(strText, GetRef("MakeXmlVar"))
                objFile.WriteLine strNewText

                objFile.Close

            Next
```